# How to start tmux session that overrides environment variables set in .bash_profile?

Tags: bash, terminal, environment-variables, tmux

Suppose I have an environment variable set inside `.bash_profile`: `export ABC=from_bash_profile`.

```
$ echo $ABC
from_bash_profile
```

When I try to create a new `tmux` session with environment variables for that specific session:

```
$ tmux new -s exp -e ABC=inside_tmux -e DEF=inside_tmux
```

...this is what I see:

```
$ echo $ABC
from_bash_profile

$ echo $DEF
inside_tmux
```

But I want `tmux` to use refer to the variables I passed when calling the `tmux new` command.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: "But I want tmux to use…" – `tmux` *does* use what you want. It's the shell that does not. `tmux` runs `bash` as a login shell and this `bash` sources `.bash_profile`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what @Kamil Maciorowski said in the comments, it doesn't seem to be possible with the `tmux new` command itself.

So, I ended up using this workaround:

```bash
tmux new -d -s xyz -n experiments -c ~/Experiments
tmux send-keys -t xyz:experiments 'export ABC=inside_tmux' Enter C-l
```

I found some other SO/SE posts useful:

- [Start tmux session which not closing after running script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64037405/11774808)
- [Tmux. Sending keys to a specific window](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39523222/11774808)